# MySQL Big Deletes

Tags: mysql

I need delete lots of rows from a large INNODB table in MySQL.

Are millions of rows in the table, this statement may take minutes, maybe hours.

I have tried this Stored Procedure without succes because I have error SQL Syntax on the Loop.

How to delete lots of rows from a large table?

```
   BEGIN
   Set @a = SELECT MIN(sId) FROM doTable;
   LOOP
      SELECT @z := sId FROM doTable WHERE sId >= @a ORDER BY sId LIMIT 1000,1;
      If @z is null
         exit LOOP
      DELETE FROM doTable
         WHERE sId >= @a
           AND sId <  @z
           AND sType IS NULL
      SET @a = @z
      sleep 3
   ENDLOOP
   DELETE FROM doTable
      WHERE sId >= @a
        AND sType IS NULL;
END
```

Comment: just checking - is it all the rows in the table you're deleting or just a select few (few to mean millions xD)

Comment: Is the data your'e managing steady? Meaning no inserts or updates are made? If so consider moving records to be kept on a new table, get rid of the old table... swap names (e.g. RENAME TABLE).

Comment: You can also drop all the indexes except the one you are using in the DELETE - unless it is the only index on the table. Even then it might worth trying (I mean drop ALL indexes, DELETE, then rebuild indexes). Some useful information here - http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig

Answer (score 5):

This is a working example, with sleep added, to be nice:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS clean_someTable;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE clean_someTable()

BEGIN   
    REPEAT
        DO SLEEP(1);
        DELETE FROM someTable 
        WHERE (created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
        ORDER BY primary_key_id 
        LIMIT 10000;        
    UNTIL ROW_COUNT() = 0 END REPEAT;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

CALL clean_someTable();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this SP in MYSQL :

```
BEGIN

REPEAT
DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE yourCondition LIMIT 10000;
UNTIL ROW_COUNT() = 0 END REPEAT;

END
```

I hope I was helpful.