# DELETE tables chunk by chunk in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I have this stored procedure that will cleanup data in various tables by supplying tid and getting the id from transactions table and store it in a temp table to avoid locks.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `CLEANUP_TABLES`(IN _iid INT, IN _limit INT)
BEGIN

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    SHOW ERRORS;
      ROLLBACK;
END;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp ENGINE=MEMORY 
SELECT id FROM transactions WHERE tid=_tid LIMIT _limit;

START TRANSACTION;
DELETE FROM TABLE A WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tmp);
DELETE FROM TABLE B WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tmp);
DELETE FROM TABLE C WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tmp);
DELETE FROM TABLE D WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tmp);
DELETE FROM TABLE E WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tmp);
COMMIT;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS tmp;

END
```

Question how can I delete chunk by chunk of those table since DATA in each table might have more than 500k of records?

Comment: You can use a loop, see e.g. [MySQL Big Deletes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51260968). Also please note that the syntax is "DELETE FROM", not "DELETE * FROM"

Comment: @Solarflare there is no voted answer to your link.. though I can try that repeat until, but should I do it on every table or On all?

Comment: You can apply this on the link solar mentioned :
REPEAT
DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE yourCondition LIMIT 10000;
UNTIL ROW_COUNT() = 0 END REPEAT;

Comment: @AliFidanli my question now is do i need to put all the DELETE inside that REPEAT? or every delete has its own REPEAT?

Comment: jordan i will add an answer below to show how it can be applied

Comment: You probably have 2 general approaches: either put only some rows in tmp and then run the deletes for those (and repeat until you reach _limit), or make a loop around each delete.

Comment: @JoerdanDevera are there any date column that we can use it to delete records by date ? As Solarflare stated , limit wont work on this scenario

Comment: @Solarflare thanks alot for feedbacks, i appreciated it

Comment: @AliFidanli Just to clarify: you cannot do `delete from tablename where id in (SELECT id FROM tmp limit 10000);` as in your approach (because of MySQL `in` limitations), but you can do `delete from tablename where id in (SELECT id FROM tmp) limit 10000`, and that's one of the two main options here (and it's what you wrote in your first comment).

Comment: @Solarflare i think it will be the best to delete using date if there is a date column inside this transaction table

Comment: @AliFidanli my question: is it correct to put all the DELETE in one REPEAT loop?

Comment: i am not sure if i got it right. but the idea of repeat  is to delete some portion of the data everytime it loops.  What do you mean by all the DELETE ? maybe add some detail on transaction table (create  statements etc ) can help me to put another answer for you

Comment: @AliFidanli because you stated to put REPEAT UNTIL.. And I put all the DELETE table inside of it.

Comment: can you share create table statement for transactions table ?